# ¿Crear elementos Html dinamicamento con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Que tal desarrolle un codigo en html y js que crea elementos input, lo que quiero lograr esque siga creando elementos al presionar el boton, lo que hace en este momento esque crea lo elementos pero al volver a precionar no crea mas elementos sino que los reemplaza este es el codigo

```js
var a = 0;

function agregarFila() {
  a++;
  document.getElementById("PRUEBA").innerHTML = "<td><input  type='text' name='Numero_Orden[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
";


}
```

```html
<div class="form-floating mb-3" id="PRUEBA">

</div>
```

Comment: concatena y no reemplaces

Comment: y esto como lo logro?

Comment: En lugar de asignación normal `=` usa concatenación `+=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como estas haciendo realmente reemplazas lo que hay en el bloque prueba.

Fíjate que pones el operador = que almacena un valor en una variable.       Para añadir nuevo contenido tienes que sumarle lo nuevo a la que ya había.

El operador más simple para esto es +=, hablando de cadenas sumar es unir o concatenar.

No se como es el código de la página, pero por el nombre de la función creo que quieres agregar filas. Lo lógico es que este grupo de celdas (td) vayan precedidas de `<tr>` y seguidas de `</tr>`.

Si PRUEBA está dentro de una tabla (entre `<table>` y `</table>`) y dentro solo hay filas de contenido pues esto te debe servir. Insisto sin ver la tabla no lo aseguro, pero podrás ajustar la solución.

```
document.getElementById("PRUEBA").innerHTML += "<tr><td><input  type='text' name='Numero_Orden[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
            <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[" + a + "]'/></td>\n\
</tr>";
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me funciono, si es un ejemplo que agregaba filas a una tabla pero al momento de pasar a version movil no se acomodaba para nada la tabla entonces entoy intentando poner inputs libres en vez de la tabla

Comment: Gracias, me alegro que funcione.

Answer (score 3):

Como te dije en mi comentario solo tienes que concatenar y no reemplazar, esto se logra haciendo uso de `+=`. Dado que estas insertando un template o varios elementos HTML, lo conveniente es usar los backtics (``` `` ```) para crear template strings y tener un código más ordenado y legible.

```js
var a = 0;

function agregarFila() {
  a++;
  document.getElementById("PRUEBA").innerHTML += `
  <td><input type='text' name='Numero_Orden[${a}]'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[${a}]'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[${a}]'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[${a}]'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[${a}]'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[${a}]'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='Observaciones[${a}]'/></td>`;

}
```

```html
<div class="form-floating mb-3" id="PRUEBA">Hola</div>
<button onclick="agregarFila();">press me</button>
```

Comment: funciono gracias por el tip de los backtics  Saludos

Comment: Es un placer ayudar :D