# No enncuentro la manera de insertar tajetas dinamicas con JavaScript en el DOM

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, dom, innerhtml

estoy intentando crear tarjetas dinamicas y mostrarlas en HTML los datos los obtengo desde un Array, los datos si son dinamicos pero solo se crea una tarjeta

```javascript
  .then((response) => {
    JSON.stringify(response.features, null, 2);

    let datos = response.features;
    console.log(datos);

    for (i = 0; datos.length; i++) {
      var organization = datos[i]["attributes"]["nombre_de_la_organizaci_n"];
      var titulo = datos[i]["attributes"]["t_tulo_del_mapa"];
      var autor = datos[i]["attributes"]["nombre_del_autor"];
      var correo = datos[i]["attributes"]["correo_electr_nico_"];
      var url = datos[i]["attributes"]["url_debe_ser_de_acceso_p_blico"];
      var descripcion =
        datos[i]["attributes"]["una_breve_descripci_n_del_mapa"];
      var img ="mobile_phone.png";


      let tarjeta = "";
      tarjeta += `
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
       <img src="${img}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="100%" width="100%">
      
       <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title"> <label>${titulo}</label></h5>
         <b class="card-text">Organization:</b> <label>${organization}</label> <br>
          <b class="card-text">Author: </label></b><label>${autor}</label><br>
          <b class="card-text">Correo: </label></b><label>${correo}</label><br>
          <b class="card-text">Descripcion:</b> <label>${descripcion}</label><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      `;
      lista.innerHTML = tarjeta;
    }
  });
```

Y esto me lo muestra asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso tengo dos campos, pero solo me muestra una tarjeta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que estoy haciendo mal, soy nuevo en JS

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/471465/54039), es exactamente el mismo caso que el tuyo.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código en donde creas el elemento `lista` y lo insertas tambén?